# Cannot stop program from crashing with wrong file entered by user

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, try-catch, raw-input

I am creating a program which asks the user to choose a file to run within the program but I can't stop the program from crashing when a file name that does not exist is entered. I have tried try statements and for loops but they have all given an error. The code I have for choosing the file is below:

```
data = []
print "Welcome to the program!"
chosen = raw_input("Please choose a file name to use with the program:")
for line in open(chosen):
    our_data = line.split(",")

    data.append(our_data)
```

Comment: Please show how you tried `try` statements. That is the correct way to do this.

Comment: `try` is the correct solution here.  Show us your code that used it.

Answer (score 3):

Add an exception:

```
data = []
print "Welcome to the program!"
chosen = raw_input("Please choose a file name to use with the program:")
try:
  for line in open(chosen):
      our_data = line.split(",")

      data.append(our_data)
except IOError:
      print('File does not exist!')
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using an exception you can simply check if the file exists and if not ask for it again.

```
import os.path 

data = []
print "Welcome to the program!"
chosen='not-a-file'
while not os.path.isfile(chosen):
    if chosen != 'not-a-file':
        print("File does not exist!")
    chosen = raw_input("Please choose a file name to use with the program:")
for line in open(chosen):
    our_data = line.split(",")

    data.append(our_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

[RTM](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

```
import sys

try:
    f = open('myfile.txt')
    s = f.readline()
    i = int(s.strip())
except IOError as e:
    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
except ValueError:
    print "Could not convert data to an integer."
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise
```